# Does get_or_create() have to save right away? (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I need to use something like get_or_create() but the problem is that I have a lot of fields and I don't want to set defaults (which don't make sense anyway), and if I don't set defaults it returns an error, because it saves the object right away apparently.

I can set the fields to null=True, but I don't want null fields.

Is there any other method or any extra parameter that can be sent to get_or_create() so that it instantiates an object but doesn't save it until I call save() on it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can just do:

```
try:
    obj = Model.objects.get(**kwargs)
except Model.DoesNotExist:
    obj = Model(**dict((k,v) for (k,v) in kwargs.items() if '__' not in k))
```

which is pretty much what [`get_or_create`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L454) does, sans commit.